# Linq placeholder for a column name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have to put a value of radioButtons dynamically into a *Linq* query, so that the value replaces the *customerName* in the code below with the value of a radioButton. This all lives within a MVC project with Entity Framework. So how can I write a placeholder in the Linq query?

```
public ActionResult Index(string whatToSearchFor, string radioButtonValue)
{
    if (search == null)
    {
        var results = from p in db.Orders
                      select p;

        ViewBag.Orders = results;
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        var results = from p in db.Orders
                      where values
                      where p.customerName.StartsWith(search)
                      select p;

        ViewBag.Orders = results;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Update and what worked for me:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string whatToSearchFor, string radioButtonValue)
{

    if(radioButtonValue == "NameOfTheRadioButton1")
    {
        var results = from p in db.Orders
                      where values
                      where p.column1.StartsWith(search)
                      select p;

        ViewBag.Orders = results;
        return View();
    }
    else if(radioButtonValue == "NameOfTheRadioButton2")
    {
        var results = from p in db.Orders
                      where values
                      where p.column2.StartsWith(search)
                      select p;

        ViewBag.Orders = results;
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        var results = from p in db.Orders
                      select p;

        ViewBag.Orders = results;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to switch from using the query syntax to using the lambda syntax.

```
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> condition = null;

if( rbFirst.Checked )
    condition = o => o.FirstThing.StartsWith( search );
else if( rbSecond.Checked )
    condition = o => o.SecondThing.StartsWith( search );
// etc...

var results = db.Orders.Where( condition );
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing me into the right direction. I just checked the value of the 'radiobutton string value', that worked for me. I will update my post.